# replacing every character with a sequence of integers

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, seq

Here is one function from my code

```
def seq():
   q=1
   n=rann()
   List=[n]
   while q<n:
       if (n % 2):
           n = 3*n + 1
           List.append(n)
       else:
           n=n//2
           List.append(n)
   if (len(List)>=len(y)):
       print(List)
   else:
       return(rann())

x=input("enter name")    #the next four lines of the code are my first trial.
y= [char for char in x]
for i in y:
    y[i]=rann()
seq()
```

I have two functions, the 1st function, rann(), generates an integer and the other(the code above) generates a sequence based on that number. I wanted to take an input x and replace every character with the sequence generated. I tried doing this

```
text = 'bat ball'

y=[char for char in text]
y[0:] = rann()
print(y)
```

For example let the input be "bat ball" so what I wanted was to replace every character of the input by every term of the sequence.
I know there is a lot of things wrong But I can't figure out another method.

Comment: Share one example of input and output

Comment: What's your input and your output? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Can you please give a sample input and the corresponding output you expect? Your wording is not so clear.

Comment: For example let the input be "bat ball" so what I wanted was to replace every character of the input by every term of the sequence.

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this? I contrived a `rann(x)` to generate the ascii code value of the character `x`, but you get the idea.

```
# example rann()
def rann(x):
    return [ord(ch) for ch in x]

def seq(n):
   q = 1
   List = [n]
   while q < n:
       if n % 2:
           n = 3*n + 1
           List.append(n)
       else:
           n = n // 2
           List.append(n)
   if len(List) >= len(y):
       print(List)
   else:
       return n

text = 'bat ball'
x = [char for char in text]
y = rann(x)
print(y)

[seq(n) for n in y]
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be useful to see what kind of integer or sequence you are trying to generate here- please post an example.

From what I can understand, you want to generate a list of numbers based on the input string?

the easiest way may be to use the ascii code for each char like this:

```
def seq():
    '''
    (None) -> List of int
    Get user input and convert to int list
    '''
    nums = []
    text = input("Enter text: ")
    for ch in text:
        nums.append(ord(ch))
    return nums
```

It is easier to just build a new list from the int values than to mutate a list that you are iterating through.

If rann generates a list of int from the char, replace ord above with rann and have it return a list of int.

A sample of you expected output would really help here.